# How to restrict Svelte transitions?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-transition

Is there a way to restrict transitions? I have trouble articulating what I mean, so I have created a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3b9be8417a284b388bddf721019fe626?version=3.46.4) illustrating the point:

- When you switch to 'AnimatedTree', you have a tree with slide transitions.
- When you then switch to another tab, you can see the tree transitioning out, which is (obviously) unwanted behavior.

Is there a way to fix this so that the transitions only apply in a certain environment?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's a [`|local` flag](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-transition-fn) for the transition (which unfortunately doesn't seem to directly solve the case, but might so do with a modified setup....) and a [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/local-transitions) on this

Comment: Yeah, I was actually aware of the `local` flag but couldn't make it work.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you only build the list elements recursively, not the whole list. From the structure it's similar to this [`tutorial`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self) which seem to behave the same when the transition is applied to the list element - also it doesn't work with the |local flag. Setting it on the whole `<ul>` though seems to be working [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e862bf252d7244db818e89e804d40bca?version=3.46.4)

Comment: I'm combining two tutorials/REPLs I found: [Tree](https://www.fareez.info/blog/creating-tree-component-using-sveltejs/) & [Tabs](https://svelte.dev/repl/cf05bd4a4ca14fb8ace8b6cdebbb58da?version=3.17.0}. For me, applying the `transition` to the `ul` did not help.

Comment: Which is probably because you have just one `ul` element and not nestes lists, like I mentioned and in the example I gave. Would try to adjust this...